# Is there a way of finding what procedures/types are used from an imported module?

Tags: fortran

The situation is the following: I am analyzing `module A` in order to find and extract an useful subroutine (say `interesting_functionality`) which I would like to incorporate in another project. The subroutine `interesting_functionality` makes use of some other modules. These modules (`module_1` and `module_2` in the example below) define in turn many types and procedures. I am sure that many of the types and procedures defined in `module_1` and `module_2` are not used in the subroutine `interesting_functionality`.

So, my question is: is there a way of finding which specific parts of `module_1` and `module_2` are made use of in the subroutine `interesting_functionality`?

```
module A
...
contains 

subroutine interesting_functionality

use module_1
use module_2 

...

end subroutine interesting_functionality 

end module A
```

Comment: There are several tools available which can help analyse this (but I won't recommend any). If you list which tools you have available, then maybe we can advise how to use them. Compilers, documentation generators, dependency analysers etc., are the type of tool one can use, but that's a broad area. That said, one reason people recommend (nearly) always using `only` clauses to `use` is for precisely this documenting reason.

Comment: @francescalus Unfortunately, I am not the programmer of this code that I am trying to use. The tools that I have available are the compiler (GNU Fortran (GCC) 10.2.0) and a documentation generator (sphinx with fotran extensions which in my experience does detect the modules called but not the specific procedures from the modules)

Comment: Can't you just comment out one of the use statements and check the compiler which methods are not defined?

Answer (score 0):

[LINUX]

Valgrind is a tool that can build a call graph. Let's assume you have the following module:

```
module A

   contains

   subroutine f1()
   end subroutine f1

   subroutine f2()
       call f1()
   end subroutine f2

   subroutine f3()
       call f2()
       call f1()
   end subroutine f3

   subroutine f4()
       call f3()
   end subroutine f4

end module A
```

and main program:

```
program main

   use A

   call f3()

end program main
```

Once Valgrind (+Qcachegrind) installed you can do the following:

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind --trace-children=yes ./your_executable

qcachegrind
```

Then using the interface you can get the following graph:

[image: call graph]

Comment: What limitations do you see with this approach? (This isn't going to capture things which aren't procedures, and presumably only those procedures which are invoked in the particular sampling run?)

Comment: @francescalus It will also capture internal procedures that are invoked and yes it will only capture the procedures that are used in that particular sampling run. Another limitation is its speed, you can't handle large programs with it (runtime > few minutes)